# How do I generate SHA1 and Key Hash in Windows 8

Tags: android, windows, ubuntu, hash, sha

I know How to `generate` **SHA1** and **Key Hash** in `Ubuntu` 12.04, but don't know How to generate in `Windows 8`

To generate `SHA1` in **Linux Ubuntu 12.04**, using following command in `terminal`:

**Debug**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

**Release**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <keystore_path> -alias <alias_name>
```

To generate `Key Hash` in **Linux Ubuntu 12.04**, using following command in `terminal`:

**Debug**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

**Release**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <alias_name> -keystore <keystore_path> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

**Note:** I have followed [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html) link to generate `SHA1` Certificate fingerprint for Debug and Release modes

Comment: CertUtil is builtin Windows utility that can be used to generate checksum, see this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/245775/is-there-a-built-in-checksum-utility-on-windows-7/898377#898377

Answer (score 0):

Its quite similar

FOR SHA1:
Open command prompt, type the following

1. cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin
2. keytool -list -v -keystore C:\PathToKeyStore -alias  -storepass password -keypass password

FOR KEYHASH:

1. download https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8e_X64.zip&can=2&q=
2. Extra to C:/
3. Go cmd and type cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin
4. keytool -exportcert -alias  -keystore "C:\PathToKeyStore" | "C:\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl" base64